# Social Media: In receipts, {$url} incorrect from SocialNetwork.tpl, SEF URL, missing buttons

Tags: civicontribute, tokens, receipts, 4.6.8, social-media

I have done a search here, bug reporting and general web search to no avail.

Platform: CiviCRM 4.6.8 on J!3.4.4

1. Problem: In CiviContribute, seems in both the receipts, webpage and email confirmation, the token {$url} is not being appended correctly for both the Twitter and Facebook buttons contained in `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/SocialNetwork.tpl`. Here are the results for both:

   Twitter:

   > Donate to Domain Name
   >   https://domain.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm

   Facebook:

   > https://domain.org/component/civicrm/?amp%3Btask=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&amp%3Breset=1&amp%3Bid=1&fb_action_ids=10206214067365432&fb_action_types=og.likes
2. Also, is there a token for grabbing whichever (SEF) URL is being used for the landing contribution form page? Or, if desired to just hand code the absolute URL, what is the format in that line?

   From the Twitter dev page the above doesn't look correct. Please confirm: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters
3. Also, on the webpage receipt confirmation, Twitter, G+, Facebook and LinkedIn are listed but in the email receipt only Twitter and Facebook buttons appear.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@BruceW

I have created an issue and included a patch.

look at here. Hopefully this resolve it.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17725

Regards
Kajan

Comment: Thanx! Will check it out today!

Comment: Thanks for fixing this partly in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17725  But the link is still being truncated in the Twitter button pretty badly.  

https://alcoholjustice.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm  

Also, know that in Test Mode for Contribution Pages it doesn't insert the $pageURL which is probably correct but could throw off a lot of users trying to test the complete experience.